# Duplicates in Linq to SQL data

Tags: c#, listview, linq-to-sql

I have a table in a SQL database which has a ID column (auto incrementing) and is set to be the primary key.  The table consists of this ID and an account name.

I then have a bit of code which reads this table and populates a listview with the data. The problem is, if I order by the account name - I get duplicates listed in the listview. If I order it by the ID, I don't see any duplicates.

The original data in the SQL database contains no duplicate account names, so obviously that's what i'd like to see in the listview.

This is the Linq i'm using to grab the data...

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client2> GetClientList()
    {
        return (IEnumerable<Client2>)from c in entity.Client2s
                                    orderby c.AccountName
                                    select c;
    }
```

And this is the code which is being used to create the listview...

```
        // Clear the listview
        listViewClient.Items.Clear();

        // Get imported client list from database
        foreach (Client2 c in SQLHandler.GetClientList())
        {
            ListViewItemClient lvi = new ListViewItemClient(c.AccountName, c);
            listViewClient.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

As I say, if I change this to **orderby c.ID** then it returns data as expected. I've also tried adding an index to AccountName. I do use a custom listview item subclass, but all that does is store a reference to the Client object.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Resolve what? You don't want the duplicates? You want to change the ordering?

Comment: You should post our code you have tried

Comment: There are no duplicates in the SQL data. Linq to SQL is creating duplicates. Hence, I'd like the data that's in the database to be the data that I see when I populate the listview.

Comment: @Simon: There must be something that you're unintentionally overlooking in the problem description, because as described it seems impossible.  At least I can't reproduce the issue here.  Can you reproduce the issue with minimum code?  Maybe show us a table with some records and a class which is a console app that does nothing but make that LINQ statement and display the erroneous results?

Comment: Added the listview creation part. This is a really odd issue. Like I said - no issues whatsoever if I order it by the unique ID. Only when I order by the account name (which are all unique anyway)

Comment: Use `Distinct`clause to exclude duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but if you don't need delayed execution of the your IEnumerable collection returned by GetClientList, I would change the method to return IList<Client2> and then ToList your LINQ query results.  I've seen "weird" things with delayed execution. I'm not saying it is the culprit, but it could be.

Comment: maybe you're doing 'join' in your linq statemants anywhere? it could be possible if you have data of clients in two (or more) tables. but as David said you have to paste more code.

Comment: Why the cast to `IEnumerable<Client2>` in `GetClientList()`? Shouldn't the return value of the linq statement already be that type?

Comment: @MGG_Soft: there are no duplicates in the data.

Comment: @Josh: Just gave that a shot but it still lists duplicates. Very odd indeed.

Comment: @trn: there are no joins. It's one table with two columns, ID and AccountName. It's a straight read from the database.  Even without involving ListViews, a Console.Writeline shows the duplicates too straight from the select method, unless I change the sort to ID.

Comment: @goric: you're right, no cast necessary. Just habit I guess!

Comment: Try this to work with a copy out the loop:

  `// Get imported client list from database 
 Client2[] myList = SQLHandler.GetClientList().ToArray(); 
 foreach (Client2 c in myList) 
 { 
  ListViewItemClient lvi = new ListViewItemClient(c.AccountName, c); listViewClient.Items.Add(lvi); 
 }`

Comment: Thanks for all the posts. I finally got to the bottom of it (and sadly it was a schoolboy error)... I DID have duplicate records in the database, but the records weren't situated beside eachother, so I never saw any duplicates when I looked (despite the fact the list should have been imported alphabetically originally anyway). It wasn't until I started displaying the ID that this became obvious because of non-sequential IDs. Apologies all, and thanks for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify for anyone else potentially reading this issue, it was programmer error. My data did indeed contain duplicates but because of the sort order, they weren't listed together and therefore I didn't see them when manually checking the data. It was only when I started displaying the ID that I realised they weren't sequential.